# Actuator endpoints not available in multi-module SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a multi module SpringBoot application that has the following modules:

- domain
- service
- persistency
- api
- application

In "api" layer I maintain all controllers and dtos and in application I add the dependencies to the modules and I build my SpringBoot (version 2.6.6) application. I am trying to add now Spring Boot Actuator with a custom info endpoint that also displays the app version and to see all endpoints in OpenAPI dashboard. For some reason, I can't get this to work, I just get 403 for everything actuator related and I don't see endpoints in OpenAPI (V3).

What I have is the following:

- in "application" I have the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

application.properties:

```
management.security.enabled = false
springdoc.show-actuator=true
```

I have also added these lines in my security config (maybe api prefix intervenes somehow)

```
.antMatchers(apiPrefix + "/actuator/**").permitAll() //I have a API prefix for all backend calls
.antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
```

In "application" as well I have defined the spring-boot-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-info</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

How do I fix my code?

Comment: do you have some filter in case you use JWT?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I have a filter but that just forwards the request if there is no jwt data present. I have other endpoints that do not require JWT and those work very well.

Comment: could you please add this filter in question. I am confident it is related with situation

Answer (score -1):

It's unclear what version of Spring Boot you're using. Starting from 2.0 you have to enable *and* expose actuator related end-points of your choice.

The following should tell you what are currently available for your application:

```
GET http://<host>:<port>/actuator
```

For example, the snippet from `application.yaml` below should enable *and* expose only the info and health end-points:

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    enabled-by-default: false
    web:
      exposure:
        include:
          - info
          - health
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
    info:
      enabled: true
```

The Spring [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.4/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator) should give you more details.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2 but by default, all endpoints but /shutdown are enabled and only /health and /info are exposed. So I don't need to add any other configuration to my code to try and make it to work. But FYI, I have tried what you say and yes, it does not work.

Comment: @2dor Interesting. We've been using the answer I gave for several Spring Boot applications that are deployed in production and it does work. The idea of explicitly enabling info and health *after* explicitly disabling all management related end-points is part of securing them along with applying proper Spring Security to them. I left out the latter for brevity. I suggest you disable Spring Security and see if it works (it should) then re-enable it and go from there.